# Quick Sort. Why does the similar implementation in Python and Javascript differs so sagnificantly?

Tags: javascript, python, sorting, quicksort

Following implementation of Quick sort in javascript with 10 000 000 random elements:

```js
function swap(arr, i1, i2) {
    const temp = arr[i1];
    arr[i1] = arr[i2]
    arr[i2] = temp;
}

function pivot(arr, l, r) {
    let pvt = arr[r];
    let i = l - 1;
    
    for (let j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < pvt) {
            i++;
            swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, i+1, r);
    return i+1;
}

function quick_sort(arr, l, r) {
    if (l < r) {
        let pvt = pivot(arr, l, r);
        quick_sort(arr, l, pvt - 1);
        quick_sort(arr, pvt + 1, r);
    }
    
}
let arr = Array.from(Array(10000000)).map((_) => Math.random());
console.time("quick_sort");
quick_sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
console.timeEnd("quick_sort");
```

It takes ≈ **1.5s** to sort an array.
When I'm testing the same one in python:

```py
import time
import random
from numpy import random

def quicksort(arr):
    qs(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)

def qs(arr, l, r):
    if l >= r:
        return
    p = partition(arr, l, r)

    qs(arr, l, p - 1)
    qs(arr, p + 1, r)

def partition(arr, l, r):
    pivot = arr[r]
    i = l - 1
    for j in range(l, r):
        if arr[j] < pivot:
            i += 1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    arr[i + 1], arr[r] = arr[r], arr[i + 1]
    return i + 1

array = random.rand(10000000)
start = time.time()
quicksort(array)

print("Seconds: ", time.time() - start)
```

It takes ≈ 131s to sort an array, if using **random.rand(10000000)**
And ≈ 60s, if using **array = [random.random() for _ in range(10000000)]** instead

Where does this difference come from?

Comment: numpy has [sort functions](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/routines.sort.html) that may be "a bit" faster

Comment: @diggusbickus that may be true but doesn't explain why the naive Javascript version is 50x faster than the naive Python version?

Comment: Different languages behave differently because they’re differently implemented.

Comment: @diggusbickus Even the built in sort functions are probably faster, no need to reach for numpy…

Comment: @deceze i mentioned numpy because op created the array with numpy, and you're totally right

Comment: did you try running your js code in Node? or did you run it in a web page?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga Ran it with node.js

Comment: @deceze Great if you can tell, which differences make Python version much slower?
I was thinking, maybe it's because of the call stack maximum size. Are there any limitations in python, which are slowing down the code.
My point is, there is no features specifically related to python, which can cause it. Btw, I took python implementation of QS from the tutorial on youtube. It's originally python code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which python interpreter you're using.

I assume you're using cpython 3 which, I believe, has no [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). You have all the overhead of an interpreted language and no tricks to speed things up.

Most modern JS engines have JIT, so the hot code paths get optimized.

Somewhat relatedly, numpy is faster because the [internal code is either C or Fortran](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/internals.html), which gets called via bindings.

Here's a longer post on [software engineering stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347908/why-hasnt-python-been-optimized-like-modern-javascript-implementations) that goes more into they why of native python not being as fast as JS.